# Better way for nested if else

Tags: python, if-statement

How can the nested if else can be done in a better way?
I want to minimize code duplication for `print "run dozer()"`

```
print "some mechanical stuffs before this"
if a == 1:
    if b == 2:
        print "run car()"
    else:
        print "run dozer()"
else:
    print "run dozer()"
print "more mechanical stuffs after this"
```

Comment: Looks good, what's the problem?

Comment: @MSeifert: well there is a tiny bit of code duplication in the "run dozer()" case. One can optimize this a bit. But indeed, this is not really an issue.

Comment: oh I haven't spotted the code-duplication. That should have been mentioned in the question :)

Comment: Let me go ahead and edit the question.

Comment: `print ("run dozer()", "run car()")[a==1 and b==2]`

Answer (score 6):

```
if a == 1 and b == 2:
    print "run car()"
else:
    print "run dozer()"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe not a good idea in this case, but you could just run your code through all (expected) cases (`0` represents not-`1` for `a` and not-`2` for `b`):

```
for a in (0, 1):
    for b in (0, 2):
        print('a = ', a, ', b = ', b, sep='')

        if a == 1:
            if b == 2:
                print("run car()")
            else:
                print("run dozer()")
        else:
            print("run dozer()")
```

This gives you a list of all combinations:

```
a = 0, b = 0
run dozer()
a = 0, b = 2
run dozer()
a = 1, b = 0
run dozer()
a = 1, b = 2
run car()
```

This gives you a list of combinations that should trigger the `run car`: `a=1, b=2`. One solution would be to use tuple-comparison:

```
if (a, b) == (1, 2):
    print('run car')
else:
    print('run dozer')
```

In this case this is quite trivial but such an approach *could* be quite senseable for more complex, deeper nested `if`s, more variables, more cases (or if you just want to be curious :-))

Answer (score 1):

You may write the same logic in one-line as:

```
print "run car()" if  a == 1 and b == 2 else "run dozer()"
```

Since Python considers `True`/`False` as 0 and 1. You may use these booleans as index to fetch the string from tuple as:

```
print ("run dozer()", "run car()")[(a, b) == (1, 2)]
```

*(This answer is inspired by  [TemporalWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3579910)'s comment)*

---

In order to further reduce the code, you may do string formatting as:

```
print "run %sr()" % ("doze", "ca")[(a, b) == (1, 2)]

# OR, via using `str.format()`
# print "run {}r()".format(("doze", "ca")[(a, b) == (1, 2)])
```

But DON'T do this. It is not as readable as compared to the previous one.

**Edit:** As per another comment by *TemporalWolf (The Great Observationist)*, since `a=1`, and `b=2`; this could be put within single boolean condition as: `0<a<b<3`. Hence, this code can be further reduced to *39 bytes*:

```
print'run %sr()'%('doze','ca')[0<a<b<3]
```

Comment: Code Golf version: `print "run "+("doze", "ca")[(a,b)==(1,2)]+"r()"` *don't do this please*

Comment: @TemporalWolf updated answer with slightly better version; again inspired from your comment :)

Comment: If a & b are ints: `print"run %sr()"%("doze","ca")[0<a<b<3]` 39 bytes. @MSeifert [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The first one is really good! But I don't think it's advisable to teach how one can index tuples with booleans. However the `0<a<b<3` suggestion is really fascinating :)

Comment: I agree with MSeifert, Code Golf is off topic for [so]. Also, pick this apart if you want: `print["Player %s Wins!"%(1+(4256>>len(b*2+a)-9&1)),"Tie!"][a==b]` It tells you who wins given "rock" "paper" "scissors" as inputs a/b

Answer (score 0):

The only code fragment that occurs twice is `"run dozer()"` so we can do analysis on the cases where this is printed: this is the case if either `a != 1` or `b != 2`. In the other case it prints `"run car()"`. So:

```
if a != 1 or b != 2:
    print "run dozer()"
else:
    print "run car()"
```

Comment: @wim: well the idea is to do an analysis what the "common code paths are". Since `"run dozer"` is the only code fragment with duplicated code, I did analysis on that one. And the condition is that this holds when `a != 1 or b != 2`.